# how to fry eggs 200+ with no green and no breakage

Tags: eggs, frying, bulk-cooking

How can I get my kitchens to fry eggs that dont go green and dont break - we fry about 300+ on gas in pans of 15 or so, put them into hotel pans & stand in bain marie until time

Comment: Perhaps you were talking about scrambled rggs. fried eggs  usually do not turn green  unless you're at the Dr. Seuss café.  When I was a banquet cook I seem to remember putting a very small amount of something acidic in with them, lemon juice or vinegar to keep them from turning green.   Sam I am.

Comment: Are you referring to the greenish-grey tinge you get on overcooked yolks?

Comment: Related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/5087/67 ... although the only one that really discusses holding them for long periods basically says 'don't do it, cook to order'

Comment: Doing this with fried would seem very unusual to me as well.  Normally, mass servings are done as scrambled because of breakage, mess, poor quality in trying to do soft yolks.

Comment: Its the fried eggs and yolks or whites - after they have stood a while (10mins+-) they start breaking up &  change colour to a greeny black.  The children have their cereal or porridge first then as soon as they have finished that then the entree is served. Its for a single sitting so they all have to be ready at the same time. I have tried adding vinegar to the cooking oil but it didnt seem to make a difference.

Comment: I think this is more about kitchen/time management than about the eggs themselves.

Comment: I cant see how to change the cooking times, the food has to be presented at the servery before the children come in and are seated - thanks all for the help and advice